# Excel table to Access query connection, [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Drive] too few parameters. expected 1

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, odbc

I'm trying to create a table in Excel, which takes data from Access Query. I'm unable to find this query listed under Data->From Access. I'm using Data->From Other Sources -> From Data connection Wizard -> ODBC DSN. On final step it throws error [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Drive]  too few parameters. expected 1.

I will not post full query at this moment, it is long

I will post subquery part (with some formatting) , that already throws this error. Can someone take a look and pinpoint where is the problem.

All queries I have work properly in Access. But I need the results export to Excel, as whole reporting VBA tool is there. (I know I can make SELECT INTO and create table, but it is not as elegant and simple to update) Thank you all for your time. Have a nice day

```
SELECT 
Employees.PersNo, 
Employees.Employee_name, 
Employees.Reporting_Month, 
Employees.Gender_Key, 
Employees.Start_Date, 
Employees.Business_Unit, 
Employees.Position_ID, 
Employees.Position, 
Employees.Local_Band, 
Employees.PS_Group, 
Employees.Wage_Amount, 
val(Employees.Bonus) AS [Bonus_%], 
val([Employees].[Commissions_(%)]) AS [Commisions_%], 
Employees.Wage_type, Employees.Wkhrs, 
Q1.Business_Unit, 
Q1.Position_ID, 
Q1.Position, 
Q1.Local_Band, 
Q1.PS_Group, 
Q1.Wage_Amount, 
[Q1].[Bonus_%], 
[Q1].[Commisions_%], 
Employees.Wage_type, 
Employees.Wkhrs,
Employees.Evid_Status



FROM Employees LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
Dateadd("m",1,[Employees.Reporting_Month]) AS Reporting_Month, 
Employees.PersNo, 
Employees.Local_Band, 
Employees.PS_Group, 
Employees.Wage_Amount, 
val(Employees.Bonus) AS [Bonus_%], 
val([Employees].[Commissions_(%)]) AS [Commisions_%], 
Employees.Wage_type, Employees.Wkhrs, 
Employees.Business_Unit, 
Employees.Position_ID, 
Employees.Position,
Employees.Evid_Status
FROM Employees WHERE Employees.Evid_Status=1 )  AS Q1 
ON (Employees.Reporting_Month = [Q1].[Reporting_Month]) AND (Employees.PersNo = [Q1].[PersNo])
WHERE Employees.Evid_Status=1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because *Position* is a [reserved word](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe) in MS Accces, simply escape the word in both outer query and subquery with backticks or square brackets.

Interestingly, while the table alias qualifier works for reserved words inside the MSAccess.exe GUI program, external ODBC calls like from Excel may fail without escaping such reserved words:

```
SELECT
...
Employees.[Position], 
...

SELECT
...
Employees.`Position`, 
...
```

Comment: Thank you, I figured what lined caused the error eventually myself by pasting line by line. Took me half a day

Answer (score 0):

You can use Excel to query Access, like you see in the link below.

http://translate.google.pl/translate?js=n&prev=_t&hl=pl&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&sl=pl&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fafin.net%2FKsiazkaSQLwExcelu%2FGraficznyEdytorZapytanSqlNaPrzykladzieMsQuery.htm

Also, consider using a parameter query to do the export from Access to Excel.

```
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim qdfTemp As DAO.QueryDef
Dim strSQL As String, strQDF As String
Set dbs = CurrentDb

' Replace NameOfTableOrQuery with the real name of the table or query,
' replace NameOfForm with the real name of the form, and replace
' ADateControlOnForm and AnotherDateControlOnForm with the real names
' of the controls on that form
strSQL = "SELECT NameOfTableOrQuery.* FROM NameOfTableOrQuery " & _
      "WHERE NameOfTableOrQuery.FieldName >= " & _
      Format(Forms!NameOfForm!ADateControlOnForm.Value,"\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#") & _
      " And NameOfTableOrQuery.FieldName <=" & _
      Format(Forms!NameOfForm!AnotherDateControlOnForm.Value,"\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#") & "';"

strQDF = "_TempQuery_"
Set qdfTemp = dbs.CreateQueryDef(strQDF, strSQL)
qdfTemp.Close
Set qdfTemp = Nothing

' Replace C:\MyFolderName\MyFileName.xls with the real path and filename for the
' EXCEL file that is to contain the exported data
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
      strQDF,"C:\MyFolderName\MyFileName.xls"

dbs.QueryDefs.Delete strQDF
dbs.Close
Set dbs = Nothing
```

Or...write data from a record set in Access to Excel.

```
Dim lngColumn As Long
Dim xlx As Object, xlw As Object, xls As Object, xlc As Object
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim blnEXCEL As Boolean, blnHeaderRow As Boolean

blnEXCEL = False

' Replace True with False if you do not want the first row of
' the worksheet to be a header row (the names of the fields
' from the recordset)
blnHeaderRow = True

' Establish an EXCEL application object
On Error Resume Next
Set xlx = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      Set xlx = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
      blnEXCEL = True
End If
Err.Clear
On Error GoTo 0

' Change True to False if you do not want the workbook to be
' visible when the code is running
xlx.Visible = True

' Replace C:\Filename.xls with the actual path and filename
' of the EXCEL file into which you will write the data
Set xlw = xlx.Workbooks.Open("C:\Filename.xls")

' Replace WorksheetName with the actual name of the worksheet
' in the EXCEL file
' (note that the worksheet must already be in the EXCEL file)
Set xls = xlw.Worksheets("WorksheetName")

' Replace A1 with the cell reference into which the first data value
' is to be written
Set xlc = xls.Range("A1") ' this is the first cell into which data go

Set dbs = CurrentDb()

' Replace QueryOrTableName with the real name of the table or query
' whose data are to be written into the worksheet
Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("QueryOrTableName", dbOpenDynaset, dbReadOnly)

If rst.EOF = False And rst.BOF = False Then

      rst.MoveFirst

      If blnHeaderRow = True Then
            For lngColumn = 0 To rst.Fields.Count - 1
                  xlc.Offset(0, lngColumn).Value = rst.Fields(lngColumn).Name
            Next lngColumn
            Set xlc = xlc.Offset(1,0)
      End If

      ' write data to worksheet
      Do While rst.EOF = False
            For lngColumn = 0 To rst.Fields.Count - 1
                  xlc.Offset(0, lngColumn).Value = rst.Fields(lngColumn).Value
            Next lngColumn
            rst.MoveNext
            Set xlc = xlc.Offset(1,0)
      Loop

End If

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing

dbs.Close
Set dbs = Nothing

' Close the EXCEL file while saving the file, and clean up the EXCEL objects
Set xlc = Nothing
Set xls = Nothing
xlw.Close True   ' close the EXCEL file and save the new data
Set xlw = Nothing
If blnEXCEL = True Then xlx.Quit
Set xlx = Nothing
```

Or, simply import the data from Access to Excel.

```
Sub ADOImportFromAccessTable(DBFullName As String, _
    TableName As String, TargetRange As Range)
' Example: ADOImportFromAccessTable "C:\FolderName\DataBaseName.mdb", _
    "TableName", Range("C1")
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, intColIndex As Integer
    Set TargetRange = TargetRange.Cells(1, 1)
    ' open the database
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & _
        DBFullName & ";"
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    With rs
        ' open the recordset
        .Open TableName, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable 
        ' all records
        '.Open "SELECT * FROM " & TableName & _
            " WHERE [FieldName] = 'MyCriteria'", cn, , , adCmdText 
        ' filter records

        RS2WS rs, TargetRange ' write data from the recordset to the worksheet

'        ' optional approach for Excel 2000 or later (RS2WS is not necessary)
'        For intColIndex = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1 ' the field names
'            TargetRange.Offset(0, intColIndex).Value = rs.Fields(intColIndex).Name
'        Next
'        TargetRange.Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset rs ' the recordset data

    End With
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Having the same error - linking Excel and Access.
After changing double quotes to single quotes the error "too few parameters. expected 1" was resolved. The sample of correct code.

```
AND all_clean.lastapp='Dial'
```